# High Acceptance rate with Uniform Proposal Distribution

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I'm using a metropolis algorithm to model a physical system. There are N sets of 8 real parameters, each set of 8 real numbers is normalized. The target is a Boltzmann distribution with the energy for one of the sets being a sum of squares of some of the 8 parameters and subtracting the squares of the others.

More exactly $f(x) = e^{-\beta E(x)}$, with $E(x) = c\sum_{i=1}^N (|\psi(i, 1)|^2 - |\psi(i, 2)|^2)$ as an example. Here, $\psi(i)$ is the ith set of 8 paramaters. the second value, 1 is the first two parameters of the ith set and 2 is the 2nd set.

The function $E(x)$ may change, but it should always really depend on the magnitude of pairs of the 8 parameters.

My problem is that even when I try a uniform distribution on the 7-sphere, the acceptance rates are around 0.85.

Is there any way to choose a proposal that gives better acceptance rates (between 0.2 and 0.5)? If not, would this mean I need to use a different algorithm altogether? (I've tried HMC, but it is incredibly inefficient).

Comment: I think that you want to choose a proposal distribution, with large variance in order to propose a candidate that is far from your current estimates. A normal distribution with large variance might be a good initial choice.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 I've tried the Von Mises Fisher distriubtion, which should effectively be the normal distribution on the sphere. For small concentration parameter (large variance), the acceptance rates are just larger. I specifically mentioned uniform, since I thought it was analagous to normal distribution with extremely large variance.

Comment: @Xi'an I have added an edit with the distribution.

Comment: The "optimal" range of $0.2/0.5$ for the acceptance rate only applies to random walk proposals. When the proposal is an independent one, such as the Uniform distribution, the higher the acceptance the better.

Comment: @Xi'an Well I tried the Von-Mises Fisher, which is more like a random walk. For this, I have tried very large and small and in between concentration parameters, only getting larger acceptance rates. Would this mean I should stick with the uniform distribution?

Comment: If the scale parameter is large enough for the Von-Mises Fisher distribution, it should be similar to the Uniform. Did you check other aspects of the simulation output to see whether or not there are differences between proposals?

Comment: @Xi'an For small concentration parameters, I found the energies to be about the same. The reason I was looking at acceptance rate was for a diagnostic of the simulation. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: I was going to suggest looking at the energies. If their distribution remains the same across proposals, I would not worry.

Comment: A further sanity check would be to run the algorithm for an extremely small value of $\beta$ and check whether or not you recover the uniform distribution.